# Calling method of a controller in the loader

Tags: php, oop, model-view-controller

This is a follow-up question to my previous one, I need to call the index() method of a controller using a loader. This is what I have come up with, in the loader. This works but I do not know whether this is is the right way of doing it. I searched google with no luck hence forced to ask.

```
public function controller($controller)
{
    $file = 'controller/' . $controller . '.php';
    $class = $controller;

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        include_once($file);
        $controller = new $class($this->registry);
        $controller->index();
    } else {
        echo 'Controller ' . $controller . ' not found';
    }
}
```

Right after instantiation of the $controller I put this `$controller->index();` to call the index method.

Also, to check if the function is callable or not I read about `is_callable` and `call_user_func` but am unsure about how to use them

```
public function controller($controller)
{
    $file = 'controller/' . $controller . '.php';
    $class = $controller;

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        include_once($file);
        $controller = new $class($this->registry);

        if (is_callable($controller)) {

        }

    } else {
        echo 'Controller ' . $controller . ' not found';
    }
}
```

Will be grateful if you could help.

Answer (score -1):

Okay, I got this and here is what I did.

```
public function controller($controller)
{
    $file = 'controller/' . $controller . '.php';
    $class = $controller;

    if (file_exists($file)) {
        include_once($file);
        $controller = new $class($this->registry);

        if (is_callable(array($controller, 'index'))) {
            return call_user_func(array($controller, 'index'));
        } else {
            echo 'Function not callable';
        }

    } else {
        echo 'Controller ' . $controller . ' not found';
    }
}
```